# Massively (bulk) reassociating torrent files with their data?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I has often happened to me, that I was moving my directory with files into another place and all torrent files start to "think" their content was lost. I was to reassociate each torrent file with it's content manually.

I think it was bad work.

Since each torrent file contains hash code of the file and each torrent application contains setup parameter for data file location. So, computer could calculate hash codes for all files in data location and reassociate each with it's torrent file.

Which client allows it? Does uTorrent allow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on whether you are on a Mac or PC and what software you are using. Because on a Mac, one can use [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com) which has an option to `Verify Local Data` from the `Transfers` menu.

According [to this site](http://filesharefreak.com/2008/11/02/utorrent-move-all-your-downloaded-files-keep-seeding/), uTorrent creates a `resume.dat` file that can be edited to match the new directory location of the files. You need to use the [`BEncode Editor.exe`](http://sites.google.com/site/ultimasites/bencode-editor#download) to open, browse & edit the `resume.dat` and change `path` of the file to match your new path. Since `BEncode` has a `Replace All` function then just use that to hang all paths in bulk.

Comment: No, no, I definitely don't want to do anything with EACH file manually. This is computer job. I want computer to do that.

Comment: While downloading torrents, I was directing them to different directories. Books -- to books directory, movies -- to movies. Also I was selecting different subcategories for books. It is impossible to change this with one "replace all" command. I think computer should search for files by checksum.

Comment: Also I see no any `resume.dat` files neither in torrent directory not in other places.

Comment: Found `resume.dat` and did find replace as you suggested. Successfully, thanks! Will select your answer if no any direct and utorrent-independent answers will appear...